# What does the adjective "Killer" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I was reading an article that contains the phrase "Hire a killer copywriter", and I'm asking about what is "killer" intended to be in this contest?

Another example for the usage of this word "Being a killer programmer".

Is it about "awesome" or "great" or "shocking" and so on?

Answer (score 2):

In this context 'killer' means 'formidably impressive'.

Source: [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/killer)

In the Advanced Learner's Dictionary this is labelled as being 'informal', but in the online version that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

In this context "killer" means "really good"/"great"/"awesome." So, yes you are correct with your observation. Does "killer" mean "shocking?" No. Something that is shocking (metaphorically) makes people's jaws drop from amazement or disgustingness. Or, electricity can shock people - which is the literal meaning.

However, if the context is talking about this person killing others, or wanting to, then it is probably referring to "killer" as the noun - someone who murders/kills another person.

For example:

- I ran a killer 10 km today = I ran a long and tiring distance today as if running so much killed me
- Hire a killer chef for the best food = Hire a very talented chef for the best food
- He killed 3 people from the restaurant, it turns out we had hired a killer chef = The chef turned out to be a killer (someone who murders)